# How can I return the list of 2 first students in the list “s”?

Tags: java, list

I'm learning java. I have trouble when I return a list of 2 first students on the list s after I sort name by alphabet. Someone help me please, thank so much. Here is my code comparator and interface.

```
@Override
public List<Student> f1(List<Student> s) {
   Collections.sort(s, new Comparator<Student>() {
       @Override
       public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
           return o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
       }
   });
    return s;
}
 List<Student> f1(List<Student> s);
```

Comment: thank for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have trouble when I return a list of 2 first students on the list s
>   after I sort name by alphabet.

You need to return

```
return s.subList(0,2);
```

where [subList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList(int,%20int)) will give you the desired portion of list as List

Comment: @AnMạnh i am glad that i could help, happy coding

Comment: A little info , the resultant list of `subList` is backed by the original list so in case you want the sublist independent of the original list then use `return new ArrayList<>(s.subList(0, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

Many possibilities... for example

```
// your code
return Arrays.asList(s.get(0), s.get(1));
```

or

```
s.stream()
    .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2)) // sort
    .limit(2)    // first two
    .collect(Collectors.toList()); // create list
```